Part of Unity ragdoll gets stuck
I added a ragdoll to my player using the Unity create ragdoll option.  Everything seems like it works except for for whatever reason, the chest of the model seems to be not working as a ragdoll and staying in its original position.



Above is my Physics debug, what is happening to my model, and my hierarchy.  I'm pretty sure its not an issue with the model because my animations work properly.
After some playing around, I think it has something to do with the Connected Body variable of the Character Joint script.  Because when I remove the legs connected body variable.  The legs don't move but the upper body moves fine.

